# Reading dynamic elements from the xml file using c#`

Tags: c#, xml

I want to read the xml elements dynamically (I mean without hard-coding the element name) from the xml file. I am not able to use the XmlReader.ReadToDescendant method as it expects a Local Name which in my case varies. For example in this case I need to read elements A, B, C, D & etc...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test Version="2010" xmlns="http://test.org/2010/values">
<A>
    <Data>
     <Somedata></Somedata>
    </Data>
    <Rows>
      <Row></Row>
      <Row></Row>
    </Rows>
</A>
<B>
    <Data>
     <Somedata></Somedata>
    </Data>
    <Rows>
      <Row></Row>
      <Row></Row>
    </Rows>
</B>
<C>
    <Data>
     <Somedata></Somedata>
    </Data>
    <Rows>
      <Row></Row>
      <Row></Row>
    </Rows>
</C>
<D>
    <Data>
     <Somedata></Somedata>
    </Data>
    <Rows>
      <Row></Row>
      <Row></Row>
    </Rows>
</D>
</test>
```

Please help me.

Comment: where are you going to get the names to read then?  from another file or from a database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's pretty simple:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
string name = GetNameFromWherever();
foreach (XElement match in doc.Descendants(name))
{
    ...
}
```

That's using LINQ to XML - a lovely API for XML if you're using .NET 3.5 or later... it's *much* nicer than using `XmlReader`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In case if I dont know the elements, Is there any way we can get the data from the XmlDocument dynamically?

Comment: @user972255: It's not clear what you mean - this is fetching the elements based on a name which can be fetched at execution time, e.g. by asking the user.

Comment: Ok. If you have more than one name then we need to have another loop on top of the descendants loop to get the names one by one?

Comment: @user972255: That would be the simplest approach, yes - or you *could* just use `doc.Descendants().Where(x => names.Contains(x.Name.LocalName))`.

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic generation of XML content into another set of classes you could do something like this:

```
class GenericNode
{
  private List<GenericNode> _Nodes = new List<GenericNode>();
  private List<GenericKeyValue> _Attributes = new List<GenericKeyValue>();
  public GenericNode(XElement Element)
  {
     this.Name = Element.Name;
     this._Nodes.AddRange(Element.Elements()
                                 .Select(e => New GenericNode(e));
     this._Attributes.AddRange(
                Element.Attributes()
                       .Select(a => New GenericKeyValue(a.Key, a.Value))
  }

  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public IEnumerable<GenericNode> Nodes
  {
    get
    {
       return this._Nodes;
    }       
  }
  public IEnumerable<GenericKeyValue> Attributes
  {
    get
    {
       return this._Attributes;
    }
  }
}

class GenericKeyValue
{
  public GenericKeyValue(string Key, string Value)
  {
     this.Key = Key;
     this.Value = Value;
  }
  public string Key { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you simply:

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(StringOfXml); // or
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(FileOfXml);

GenericNode rootNode = new GenericRode(rootElement);
```