# LINQ to XML Get all node names from file

Tags: c#, mysql, xml, linq, parent-child

I got a XML file like this.

```
Parent
-Value
-Value
-Child
--Value
--Value
---Grandchild
----Value
---GrandchildEND
-ChildEND
-Value
-Child2
......
```

Structure of the XML file is variable. Means each XML has different Childs , Grandchilds, etc.
I want to open the XML file, and input the data from the XML file to a MYSQL database.

Here the Code i use to open the XML and input the information to MySQL.

```
                while (hardcore < 50000)
            {
                try
                {
                    XDocument xmlDoc2 = XDocument.Load("c:\\a.xml");
                    var simpleQuery2 = (from Mainparent in xmlDoc2.Descendants("Mainparent")
                                        select Mainparent).FirstOrDefault();
                    dbcon.Insert
                        (
                        simpleQuery2.Element("id").Value,
                        simpleQuery2.Element("action").Value,
                        simpleQuery2.Element("ordernr").Value,
                        simpleQuery2.Element("typ").Value,
                        simpleQuery2.Element("orderdate").Value,
                        simpleQuery2.Element("p4code").Value,
                        simpleQuery2.Element("runtime").Value,
                        );
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "did a stupid mistake mofo";
                }
                hardcore++;
            }
```

the information from "simpleQuery2.Element("id").Value" is a Value Stored in the MainParent.

My Problem is now:

I cant be sure which values/childs/grandchilds.. are inside the XML file.
So to successfully import it into the MySQL i would need to import all the elements each by each, cause else i get a error and the import doesnt work.

I need to know Parent/Valuename/Value  or Parent/Child/Valuename/value.
because Parent/Valuename/Value will be imported into the table "PARENT"
and  Parent/Child/Valuename/value will be imported to the table "CHILD".

If i know Which Childs/Grandchilds are, i know what values to expect.

I Already can get a full list of the element with:

```
            XDocument xmlDoc2 = XDocument.Load("c:\\a.xml");
        foreach (var name in xmlDoc2.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
                .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct())
        { textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "\r\n"+name; }
```

Comment: So [What Have you Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) to do in code (show us the code please)?

Comment: You need to be specific in what you're asking. Show us the XML. Show us what you want to get out of it. Show us what you tried.

Comment: i tried to get the node list with the xelement but that kinda didnt work out. since it telling me xmlDoc2.Attributes() is not possible. Sorry cant post the XML, since i dont have actually one. I just got a description of the structure.

Comment: .. jesus ..u guys were way to fast... but you are right. ill write a better description tomorow with a decent code sample.

Comment: So i edited my post, i hope i describes the problem better now.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still a bit vague. The reason I feel it's still a bit vague is because you state each XML is different, but I'm not sure how that relates to the Parent/Child/... flow.

```
var nodeNames = XDoucment.root.Descendants()
                              .Select(e => e.Name.Localname)
                              .Distinct()
                              .ToList()
```

This code will give you a list of *all* the distinct node names in your XML file.

I've answered a similar question Titled
[Reading dynamic elements from the xml file using c#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7960080/reading-dynamic-elements-from-the-xml-file-using-c/7960427)

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. But i also just get all the nodes listed with that.' XDocument xmlDoc2 = XDocument.Load("c:\\a.xml");
            var nodeNames = xmlDoc2.Root.Descendants()
                                          .Select(eh => eh.Name.LocalName)
                                          .Distinct()
                                          .ToList();

           listBox1.Items.AddRange(nodeNames.ToArray()); ' but i would like to have the child nodes combined with their parent nodes. item = Parent item 2 = Partent/childXY item 3 = Parent/ChildXY/GrandchildZHU item 4 =Parent/ChildASD

Answer (score 0):

To get all XML nodes, just use this:

```
XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument(); 
xml_doc.Load(something);
XmlNodeList list = xml_doc.SelectNodes("//*");
```

If you want something more, just modify the XPath expression :).

Comment: Hi thx , i tried to do it like you said, but i only get "System.Xml.XPathNodeList" as result. my code is `XmlDocument xml_doc = new XmlDocument();
            xml_doc.Load("c:\\a.xml");
            XmlNodeList list = xml_doc.SelectNodes("MainParent");
            textBox1.Text = list.ToString();`